# Tooltip bootstrap isn't showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm importing Bootstrap 3 from cdn and I cannot make work the tooltip

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

Source https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to init all your `tooltips` using the `.tooltip()` method:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

Please take a look at the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips-usage

Comment: Thnaks, but I don't understand why it worked without the js part

Comment: @executable It can't work without the `js` part :/ Where did you see that ?

Comment: Well on my js file I didn't included any js for declaring the tooltip, i'll check in my commit anyway

Comment: @executable Well can you please `upvote` and `validate` my answer ? ;)